# How to import a self-signed certificate in a vue app

Tags: vue.js, certificate

I generated a self-signed PKCS-12 certificate with keytool(java sdk) for the API which is built in java Spring. Then, I imported the same certificate in Chrome certificates, but I don't understand why when I run my application is not using the certificate. It seems to generate a localhost certificate of its own.  This is my vue.config.js:

```
let fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: "8081",
    https: {
      ca: fs.readFileSync('C:\\Projects\\LicentiaUtilities\\books.p12')
    },
  }
}
```

Is the PKCS12 format not supported? Should I convert into something else?

Answer (score 1):

Your certificate won't work on localhost, all certificates work only with domain names.

There is no way to issue SSL certificate for an IP address or localhost; you have to have an actual name which you create the certificate for. In order to get such a name, you need a DNS. Since you don't have access to the internal DNS of that local network, you will have to use a public DNS server for this.

If you will publish your app, I'll recommend you nginx, it's super easy to add ssl cert, and make a reverse-proxy to your NodeJS instance.

Comment: My thought was to use self-signed certificates, of course for testing purposes only, since it won't work in production like that.

Comment: @2eety if you need SSL for test purposes only, you should definitely check out ngrok.com/

Comment: Ah, I see, since I know it generates a random domain and it's no longer localhost. Of course, I don't really know how it works under the hood, but that should work. Also, the thing that has been bugging me is that I generated the certificate and it works fine with postman(after importing the certificate), that's why I was thinking that it should've worked with the browser as well.